# Find the probaility of two events, which intersect is empty set

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Find 
P[A]-?
P[B]-?
If А ∩ B= ∅ and A,B-independent
I know that P[A]=P[AB]/P[B], but I don't know how to find P[∅].
Can you help me?

Comment: $\Pr(\emptyset)=0$.  It will be more convenient to use $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$.

Comment: But it is mean, that 0=P[A] *P[B]. But in P[A]=P[AB]/P[B] and P[B]=P[AB]/P[A] => P[A] != 0 and P[B] != 0.  p.s. (!= it is not =)

Comment: My suggestion about not dividing is to avoid the hazards of dividing by $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\cap B=\varnothing$ and $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $$\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(A\cap B)+\mathbb P(A\cap B^c)=0, $$
as $A$ and $B^c$ are independent.